# binary and multiclass classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, naive-bayes, multi-class

I have a simple yes/no problem so I was naturally inclined towards using a binary classifier because I was reading the book, [A Course in
Machine Learning](http://ciml.info/dl/v0_9/ciml-v0_9-all.pdf) by Hal Daumé III and I quote from it:

**[ Binary Classification:** trying to predict a **simple yes/no response.**
For instance, predict whether Alice will enjoy a course or not.
Or predict whether a user review of the newest Apple product is
positive or negative about the product.

**Multiclass Classification:** trying to put an example into **one of a number
of classes**. For instance, predict whether a news story is about
entertainment, sports, politics, religion, etc. Or predict whether a
CS course is Systems, Theory, AI or Other. **]**

But then my professor told me to try using **naive Bayes and KNN** for my problem which (according to the image I've attached below) are **multiclass classifiers**.

**So can it be beneficial to use multiclass classifiers for a simple binary problem?** I'm probably going to try a lot of classifiers to get the best accuracy but before going straight into practical tests I wanted to get some advice because due to the abundance of classifiers I'll have to pick a few(and choose the one providing the best results) and that choice must be based on a certain reasoning.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have only two classes it doesn't matter what is the classification rule (one-vs-all or mutually exclusive classes) since for two classes they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think too much about multi-class vs extension to binary. It's really not that hard.

Some statistical methods are binary classification, e.g. logistic regression. We can still extend it to multi-class by fitting several times and combine them like in your diagram.

We also have some statistical algorithms that can handle multi-class by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Before i answer your question, i would like to stress that i'm not agree with the bullet point "$a$ vs. $\neg a$" in the slide. Imagine you want to classify pictures according to the class "apples". You have dozens of training pictures of apples and nothing else that describes what is "**not an apple**". So if you must judge for an unseen picture whether if it belongs to the class $a =\textrm{apple}$ or $\neg a = \textrm{not an apple}$ you are not facing a binary but a unary classificastion problem (also known as *one-class-classificastion problem*).

Binary classification deals with the problem where two classes can be truly modelled in terms of existing traing samples or more concrete existing features. But if we have a case where we must find out if an objecgt belongs to a class or not, then we are not longer talking about **discrimination** of multiple classes but **recognition** of a single class.

And now lets focus on your question: binary is in fact a multiclass-classification problem. Even more, a binary (or a multiclass) classification problem, can be seen as a sequence of $n$ unary classification problems, where $n$ denotes the number of classes. There are plenty of papers on this topic. I suggest to read a little bit on it. I am sure that your yes/no prediction problem falls into this category.

[One-class classification. Concept-learning in the absence of counter-examples](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/n9d04/thesis.pdf)

[A Survey of Recent Trends in One Class Classification](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~s255khan/files/occ_survey09.pdf)

[One-Class versus Binary Classification: Which and When?](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6406735/)